# SharePoint Online - Teams Chat Messages Notifications and Conversations

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, microsoft-teams

Is it possible in SharePoint online instead of directing the users to teams, have a pop-up on the same screen at the bottoms of a page with the same chat experience in Teams?

If so, can someone please provide an example of an existing web-part that achieve the above?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such web part that can meet your needs.

You can share your feedback to Microsoft [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/).